# Run cron in Golang while having different databases

Tags: mongodb, go, cron

I am working on a SaaS based project on which Merchants can subscribe to set up their online store.

**Project Overview**

I am using Golang (backend), Mongodb database service and Angular4 (frontend) to build the system. I have multiple merchants that can set up their store. Each merchant has its own url (having its business name as subdomain in the url) to connect to his database.

For Routing, I am using Golang's Gin framework at back end.

**Problem**

I want to run the cron jobs for the merchant-specific database. In these cron jobs there are some operations that need to connect to the database. But in my routing, until a route for an API is called, the database won't be set. And ultimately, the cron does not run with proper data.

**Code**

**cron.go**

```
package cron

import (
    "gopkg.in/robfig/cron.v2"
    "controllers"
)
func RunCron(){ 
  c := cron.New()
  c.AddFunc("@every 0h1m0s", controllers.ExpireProviderInvitation)
  c.Start()
}
```

**Controller function**

```
func ExpireProviderInvitation() {
    bookingAcceptTimeSetting, _ := models.GetMerchantSetting(bson.M{"section": "providers", "option_name": "bookings_accept_time"})
    if bookingAcceptTimeSetting.OptionValue != nil{
        allInvitations, _ := models.GetAllBookingInvitations(bson.M{ "status": 0, "send_type": "invitation", "datetime": bson.M{"$le": float64(time.Now().Unix()) - bookingAcceptTimeSetting.OptionValue.(float64)} })
        if len(allInvitations) > 0 {
            for _, invitationData := range allInvitations {
                _ = GetNextAvailableProvider(invitationData.Bid, invitationData.Pid)
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**router.go**

```
func NewRouter() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(gin.Recovery())
    router.Use(SetMerchantDatabase)

    public := router.Group("/api/v1")
    for _, route := range publicRoutes{
        switch route.Method {
            case    "GET"   :   public.GET(route.Pattern, route.HandlerFunc)
            case    "POST"  :   public.POST(route.Pattern, route.HandlerFunc)
            case    "PUT"   :   public.PUT(route.Pattern, route.HandlerFunc)
            case    "DELETE":   public.DELETE(route.Pattern, route.HandlerFunc) 
            default         :   public.GET(route.Pattern, func(c *gin.Context){
                                    c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                                        "result": "Specify a valid http method with this route.",
                                    })
                                })
        }
    }
    router.NoRoute(controllers.UnauthorizedAccessResponse)
    router.Run(":8080")
}

func SetMerchantDatabase(c *gin.Context){
    subdomain := strings.Split(c.Request.Host, ".")

    if len(subdomain) > 0{
        config.Database = subdomain[0]
        config.CurrentBusinessName = subdomain[0]
    }else{
        errMsg := "Failed: Invalid domain in headers."
        response := controllers.ResponseController{
            config.FailureCode,
            config.FailureFlag,
            errMsg,
            nil,
        }
        controllers.GetResponse(c, response)
        c.Abort()
    }
    c.Next()
}
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "cron"
)

func main(){
    cron.RunCron()
    NewRouter()
}
```

**Explanation of above code**

An example route can be:

```
Route{ "AddCustomer", "POST", "/customer", controllers.SaveCustomer },
```

An example API url can be:

http://business-name.main-domain.com/api/v1/customer

Where "business-name" is the database which is set whenever an API is called.
I want to run my cron without calling an API route.

**Alternative approach**

In Shell script, we can run cron by hitting url as a command. For this, I can create a url to run it as a command. But this is my theoratical approach. Also I don't know how will I get different merchant databases.

I am not sure if this approach will work. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would do well to use `gofmt`. Your code currently is very hard to read.

Comment: Where is `config` defined? It looks like a global variable... if that's true, then your code is incredibly racy and buggy.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, Config is a package which is being used in other packages. It holds some global variables to be used by the system. The code is not buggy, it is simply using config global variables to generate correct output.

Comment: Okay, then your code is terribly buggy. Having middleware set a global variable is a sure way to a) make your program crash, b) access the wrong database randomly.

Comment: And I assure you, your code is buggy. Setting a global variable as you do, is racy. If two requests happen at the same time, they will collide and your program will crash with a data race. If two requests happen at nearly the same time, one is liable to use the other's database configuration. Unless you intend your program to crash, and to use the wrong database, these are bugs.

Comment: Thanks for identifying these bugs. Actually, I am new to Golang. And this is my First Go project. So Can you guide me over why I should not declare globals in config. Or if there is any tutorial or article available about this, You can provide that also.

Comment: Connection-scoped variables _are not config_. Treating them as such leads to this sort of problem. In any language. It has nothing to do with Go. Scope your variables properly, and this won't be an issue.

Comment: @Flimzy I have build the REST api to serve content on different routes, In order to connect to DB I had to setup it as config. Can you guide me to approach it properly. As you are explaining you must have worked on this type of requirement and can guide me ( or provide me the tutorial links ) in answer

Comment: I think you just need to do some refactoring; having the DB selection tied to request handling makes creating your cron job unnecessarily difficult. Having a shell script make a localhost GET request is even worse. Your request handlers and cron task should both get their DB connection from elsewhere; the request handlers from the router, the cron task from command line, env, or config file.

Comment: @Adrian As I mentioned each merchant will have separate API url http://merchant.domain.com/api/v1/customer  and each API needs to get the data from merchant specific database ( I create a new DB for each merchant on singup ) , so what would be the best way to do it ?

Comment: Yeah, I read the question. If you're talking about a cron job, you need to stop thinking about URLs. A cron job doesn't get accessed by URL. As I wrote in my previous comment, the cron job should receive its configuration from command line, config file, or env vars.

Comment: @Adrian I am trying for the same but not sure how can I do it. Do you have any idea or any tutorial, reference link on this ?

Comment: A simple web search should turn up a ton of resources on these topics. Requesting recommendations for off-site resources is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161981/discussion-between-amandeep-kaur-and-adrian).

Comment: Proper program organization is not a simple matter of "follow N steps." It's a learned skill. It can take years to master it. It's well beyond scope for a SO question. The bite-sized version is rules like "don't use global variables", which in this case, would get you a long way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adapt `SetMerchantDatabase` to work independently of your router. Then you can have it set things for Cron just as well.

Comment: @Filmzy, To work `SetMerchantDatabase` independently of Router, How will I get database name as for now it is coming from a url that hits an API. I would probably need the url from which I can get the database name.

Comment: Can not we use shell scipt for this ?? I searched a lot for this but could not find any appropriate content for my requirement.

Comment: Your program is just very poorly designed. There's not a correct way to fix it, as it's entirely wrong at present.